# How to change hover link colour for blog post (body) text only

Tags: css, links

I am using the Shamrock theme and I am happy with link colours on the main page however when you go into a blog post and hover over any links within the body they are red.

I have tried multiple things with CSS (after hours of googling as I do not know CSS) and without using !important and therefore changing ALL links I can't get just the links within the blog posts to change when hovering over them.

Is anyone able to help with this, please?

Comment: I would like the links to be this colour when hovering, #e164af

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! For anyone else with the this question, this worked for me:

```
.entry-content a:not(.more-link):not(.wp-block-button__link):hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Change colour for one you prefer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the page ID then set the class to reflect it.

For example:

```
body.page-id-1,body.page-id-2,body.page-id-3 {
     background-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding.

How would I find the page ID? Sorry, don't know anything about CSS really and only managed to experiment with some stuff earlier by googling!

Comment: https://www.wpentire.com/page-id-wordpress/

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I've had a look through this and unfortunately, I don't think it will work for my blog as I don't have a page for it. My blog posts are visible from the home page, not via a separate one.

Comment: Cant you use your homepages ID if they appear there?

Comment: Tried searching how to find that out but can't seem to find an id for my homepage.

Comment: The homepage itself is identified as the Main Index Template (index.php). You can add custom CSS in the following way.
wp-admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS.

Comment: That's how I've been adding CSS, I've tried multiple things from various already answered questions at other forums etc however nothing seems to work apart from the following:

a:hover {
color: #e164af !important;
}

However, this changes ALL links not just the links within each separate blog post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the body class to nesting each anchor tag.

This is for the blog post page:

```
.blog a:hover {
    color: #e164af;
}
```

And, this is for the blog post detail pages:

```
.single a:hover {
    color: #e164af;
}
```